# NativeScript SideDrawer a mess?

Tags: angular2-nativescript

**Is the SideDrawer not working in NativeScript? If so, I can leave it and look for another solution.**

I'm testing out NativeScript to see if it is something for my project. Doing this tutorial http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1 it felt really promising.

But then I tried to add a sideDrawer and everything just became extremely confusing. It seems like there are a lot of different versions on how to use the SideDrawer and the tags are different: RadSideDrawer, SideDrawer etc.

I tested these (and others):
https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-cross-platform-native-sidedrawer-component-in-nativescript

http://www.techumber.com/navigation-drawer-side-drawer-for-nativescript/

All of the attempts I've made have resulted in different kind of errors from segmentation fault when starting up or null pointer exception when not being able to call openDrawer on the RadSideDrawer (or whatever it is supposed to be called).

I just want to have a sidedrawer in my app... Had no idea that it could be so complex.

Comment: I found sample application using Angular2 that is using the sideDrawer. Will test that. https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular

Answer (score 1):

A good sample (also listed in nativescript-snacks and tweeted by nativescript) ist the sidedrawer-template from shripalsoni04:

https://github.com/shripalsoni04/nativescript-angular-drawer-template

It worked well for me on Android (just make sure you download everything, including the icons from `App_Resources`! Otherwise, the sidedrawer won't display!). Also good to know: It actually uses the nativescript-telerik-ui sidedrawer (so make sure everything is installed correctly there as well => also check package.json for right dependencies).